# mySQL Pagination With @row_number/rank

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong here.  This has worked for me in the past, but that may because I was using MariaDB and now this is mySQL 8.  I am trying to pagination with rank.  Is this SQL no longer valid on mySQL 8? Is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) as 'rank',
        a.* 
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            deals.id
        FROM
            deals
        ) AS a 
    ORDER BY
        utc_created DESC 
    ) AS x,
    ( SELECT @row := 0 ) AS r 
WHERE
    1 = 1 
    AND rank >= 1 
    AND rank < 51 
ORDER BY
    rank ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rank is a reserved word, and i think your table r is in the wrong position

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        @rownum := @rownum + 1 'rank',
        a.* 
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            foo.id
        FROM
            foo
        ) AS a ,
    ( SELECT @rownum := 0 ) AS r 
    ORDER BY
        utc_created DESC 
    ) AS x
WHERE
    1 = 1 
    AND `rank` >= 1 
    AND `rank` < 51 
ORDER BY
    `rank` ASC
```

Comment: You were correct, it was the reserved word of 'rank', I changed it to 'rowrank' in all the spots and it worked fine.  Thank you very much for your help!!!